# How to set the width:fit-content property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in javascript, how can I set an element (div) with id="container? My option is like this, but it doesn't work.

```js
$('#container').style.height = fit_content
```

You can use jquery, or you can without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `jQuery`:

```
$('#container').css('height', 'fit-content');
```

Without:

```
document.getElementById('container').style.height = 'fit-content';
```